# How to toggle yes/no field in modern sharepoint list based on what other yes/no field is selected

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list, modern

Eg:if fruit is selected yes than vegetable field should toggle to no and vice versa

Comment: You can do this by customising the list form using PowerApps.

Answer (score 0):

You could create flow as following pictures show.
[image]
[image]